# How to write a customized panel in WPF or Windows Store?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, windows-store-apps, panel

I tried hard to find some resource on how I can write my own panel, but no luck... I have searched for a sample, and didn't find anything either... I don't know how the framework treats the Width and Height and Margin properties of the Elements, and how it tells them where and with what size they should draw themselves...

A sample will help a lot. Any further will be appreciated as well.

And I think that it's worth noting that I write codes in Visual Basic, but am completely familiar with C#, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a good sample for introduction on Panels: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15705/FishEyePanel-FanPanel-Examples-of-custom-layout-pa

Comment: I am not aware of any differences. I wrote a simple custompanel for a Windows Store app and the code could be used in both worlds. You still need to override the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride Methods.
Do you face any concrete problems?

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio at the time. I'll answer back as soon as possible.